# How to deploy react js in existing Codeigniter project

Tags: codeigniter, reactjs, react-router

I am using Codeigniter 2.0 Framework. I need to use react type script to load view. I am using Nginx server. How to deploye react js with existing project and port also.

Comment: Have you check how [this guy](https://github.com/makasimenator/codeigniter-reactjs-example) completed that? His CI is 2.2.6 version. Pay attention on views directory where you need to install JS dependencies. Disclaimer: didn't use it, just found googling.